Why can't Java resolve the Symbol 'Github'?
I am working on a simple music app in Android Studio and I want to import following project
(https://github.com/hexise/jaudiotagger-android) in order to change the name of the metadata (like album name) of the .mp3-files on the phone.
When I want to import a class like AudioFile like this in my Activity:
 import com.github.hexise.jaudioTagger.AudioFile;
I get the error that the symbol 'github' is not resolvable.
even though I imported it in my build and settings.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.musica'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.musica"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


}


dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.hexise:jaudiotagger-android:'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'


}

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Musica"
include ':app'



A Jitpack artifact needs to use the pattern com.github.User:Repo:Version, therefore you need to specify a version.
You need to specify a version to be used. As the project does not have releases or tags you need to use the commit hash you want to use or the branch name + snapshot: master-snapshot. See Jitpack documentation https://jitpack.io/docs/
Therefore one working Gradle implementation statement would be for example
implementation com.github.hexise:jaudiotagger-android:master-SNAPSHOT

The second  problem is your import statement. The artifact name does not have to have any relation to the Java class and package name.
You have to look into the source code and get the correct package name of the AudioFile class. In this case it is
package org.jaudiotagger.audio;

Therefore the correct import statement is
import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFile;


Thank you for your answer. I wrote implementation 'com.github.hexise:jaudiotagger-android:master-SNAPSHOT' into the gradle file  and import com.github.hexise:jaudiotagger-android:master-SNAPSHOT; into the Activity class but I still get the same error.

@Wotan2004 sorry I made a similar mistake like you and mixed up the class name and the artifact name but both do not have nothing in common I this case. I have now corrected that in my answer. BTW with a correct Gradle configuration thus the correctly added artifact name Android Studio should have provided you as fix to add the correct import statement.

Thanks for the second. I now wrote import org.jaudiotagger.audio.AudioFile; into my Activity class and I wrote implementation com.github.hexise:jaudiotagger-android:master-SNAPSHOT into build.gradle. But that still doesn't work. I am quite new so my question is whether I need to download that github project or that gradle does this automatically?

@Wotan2004 May be this project can not be used via Jitpack as it does not include any artifact definition. I juts noticed that this project only contains the plain source code and a readme, I assume Jitpack can not work with such a project. Looking at the forks of this project you may have more luck with https://github.com/blackpill/jaudiotagger-android as it contains a pom.xml, making it a Maven artifact. Also check out the other forks as they seem to contain interesting fixes and updates.
